# Trying to list attributes in bash 4 by nested for loops

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting, centos-7

This is going to be difficult to explain but I am going to give it a shot.  This snippit is working in bash 5.0.16 but not 4.2.46

I have an array basicHosts=(host1 host2 host3) this is a dynamically generated array, the names could change at any time.  I have used this array to create 3 variables whoes names are the values in basicHosts.  Right now I have this:

```
host1=(Name CPU Memory IP)
host2=(Name CPU Memory IP)
host3=(Name CPU Memory IP)
```

What I want to do is to loop through each variable defined in basicHosts and to print out the values.  Below is what I have tried that is working in bash 5

```
#At this point each host should have its own matrix
#Now we need to set values for each host
echo "Here is what the hostname matrix looks like"

for host in "${basicHosts[@]}"
    do
        temp=$host
        for attr in "${temp[@]}"
            do
                echo $attr
            done
    done
```

I am brand new to bash do pardon my poor formatting.  Just trying to learn by doing.  Hopefully yall have some advice.

EDIT:  The full code

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
hostSet="True"
defaultSet="False"

declare -a basicHosts
basicHosts=(host1 host2 host3)


clear
echo "Hello, below are the default hosts that will be created
"
declare -i i=0

for hosts in "${basicHosts[@]}"
do
    echo "$i: $hosts"
    i=$i+1
done

echo "Hosts are Set"


#Going to start creating the arrays based off of the host names

for host in "${basicHosts[@]}"
    do
        declare -a $host
        eval "$host=(Name CPU Memory)"
    done

echo "Variable matrix created"
#At this point each host should have its own matrix
#Now we need to set values for each host
echo "Here is what the hostname matrix looks like"


for host in "${basicHosts[@]}"
    do
        typeset temp="$host"

        echo $host
        for attribute in "${temp[@]}"
            do
                echo "${host[$attribute]}"
            done


    done
```

Comment: You might want/need to use associative arrays, `bash4+` has that feature afaki.

Comment: I thought of that approach but Im not sure I wont run into the same problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713104/loop-over-tuples-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

The problem here resides in declaring host1, host2 & host3 as an **arrays** and not **variables** to **basicHosts** array and also use **concatenation**, here is another approach to resolve the issue :

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#At this point each host should have its own matrix
#Now we need to set values for each host
echo "Here is what the hostname matrix looks like"
declare -a basicHosts

## allhosts array here contains n hosts 
for host in allhosts ; do 
    # You can make any treatment here
    basicHosts+=( ${host[*]} )
done

for host in "${basicHosts[@]}" ; do
        for temp in "${host[@]}" ; do
                  echo "${host[$temp]}"
        done
done
```

**EDIT :**

Since the last edit, Each host should be iterable and every value on it (Name, CPU , Memory) should be iterable too. This can be achieved using associative array + string to array conversion, Here is an update of you the code to use.

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
hostSet="True"
defaultSet="False"

declare -a basicHosts
basicHosts=(host1 host2 host3)
clear
echo "Hello, below are the default hosts that will be created
"
declare -i i=0

for hosts in "${basicHosts[@]}"
do
    echo "$i: $hosts"
    i=$i+1
done

echo "Hosts are Set"
#Going to start creating the arrays based off of the host names
declare -A results
for host in "${basicHosts[@]}"
    do  
        values="Name CPU Memory"
        arrayvalues=(${values})
        results+=( ["$host"]="${arrayvalues[@]}")

    done
echo "Variable matrix created"
#At this point each host should have its own matrix
#Now we need to set values for each host
echo "Here is what the hostname matrix looks like"
echo "---------------------------------"
array=(${results[${host}]})
for host in "${!results[@]}" ; do
echo -ne "${host} : "
    for value in "${array[@]}" ;do 
        echo -ne "$value - "
    done
    echo -e "\n"
done
echo "---------------------------------"
```

The output should look like :

```
Here is what the hostname matrix looks like
---------------------------------
host2 : Name - CPU - Memory -

host3 : Name - CPU - Memory -

host1 : Name - CPU - Memory -

---------------------------------
```

Comment: The problem with that approach is that the basicHosts list is dyanmic.  I am using host1, 2, and 3 as placeholders for this example.  I believe I need to be able to take an array of values (IE host1 host2 host3) and create arrays off of those names.  I have edited my post to show more of the code.

Comment: It's not clear for me, what is rabbit arrays for, i have edited the answer with adding concatenation for each new host you can add it to basicHosts.

Comment: Sorry should've remove rabbit lol.  I'll try this in the morning.  What is the difference with * and the @?   Why did you add allhosts?  In my code basicHosts contaibs n hosts already.  Just curious

Comment: Ok, so if it contains already the hosts, no need for it you can use basicHosts instead. the difference between * & @ is that * will deal with the list as one argument. In your case you can use @ also, there is no impact here.

Comment: See this still isn't doing it for me.  It is still just outputting host1 host2 host3.

Hosts are Set
Variable matrix created
Here is what the hostname matrix looks like

host1
host1
host2
host2
host3
host3

I am looking for it to say:
host1
Name
CPU
Memory
host2
Name
CPU
Memory
host3
Name
CPU
Memory

Comment: I have added the full code so you can run it on your system

Comment: @SureThing Are the values for `Name CPU Memory` just that and static or do those contain actual values. So is the `Name CPU Memory` part of the iterations literal or are those placeholders for changing values?

Comment: They are just placeholders.  After I figure out just how to reference them and display them then I can work on editing them

Comment: @SureThing Is Reda code still not doing it for you? If it were PowerShell or Windows I could help maybe. I think perhaps Reda doesn't see you are using eval to get the value of `$host`. I always have to test extreme with Linux scripts myself. Is the problem with the solution Reda provide that the host matrix output where those rows have `host# : Name - CPU - Memory -` that it needs to be values in place of `Name`, `CPU`, and `Memory` rather than those names? I'm just confused how those are returning values but I'm not a Linux scripting expert and I always have to play a lot with Linux scripts.

Comment: @SureThing Additionally, you might consider an edit and give an example of what one set of dynamic values might look like and then show an example of your expected output with those values. I'm wondering if literal placeholder values and all causing confusion because loops within loops to get values of objects within other objects and such.